# How to wrap text around circular carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my text to wrap around my image (styled to be circular) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBo7R.png), but instead of a regular image, I want to use a carousel. When I use the carousel, however, the text wraps like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mQs1.png).

I achieved the first with the following code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="w-100">
  <div id="circle-wrap"><img align="left" class="curve img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" width="300px" src="img/main.png" alt="">
    <h4 align="left" class="mb-0"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#circle-wrap .curve {
   height: auto;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   float: left;
   margin-right:2rem;
   border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-inside:circle();
   shape-outside:circle();
}
```

And this is the code I have for the carousel:

HTML:

```html
<div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img align="left" class="curve img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="img/ig.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#carouselControls .curve {
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-inside:circle();
  shape-outside:circle();
}
```

I can't seem to find any way to correctly combine the two. Could anyone help?

Comment: give a height and width to your images in order to use shape-outside effectively. Also your circle needs a % in the the brackets. Have a look at [this link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started) and this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/2wckn34e/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) CSS property define a circular shape on your image so that the inline text next to it flow around the shape like this:

```css
.shape-circle {
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />


<div class="w-100">
  <div id="circle-wrap"><img align="left" class="curve img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2 shape-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="">
    <h4 align="left" class="mb-0"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you have that, it works the same way within your carousel.

```css
.shape-circle {
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />


<div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img align="left" class="curve img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2 shape-circle" src="https://picsum.photos/id/390/300/300">
   <h4 align="left" class="mb-0"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

If you want your text to be outside a carousel item, you might need to override some of the carousel-item css.

```css
.shape-circle {
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}

.carousel-item {
  width: 300px !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />


<div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active shape-circle">
      <img align="left" class="curve img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2 " src="https://picsum.photos/id/390/300/300">
    </div>
    <h4 align="left" class="mb-0"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```